# Is it possible to place a loader image inside an iframe while its loading its content?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html, dom

I'm working inside a Facebook tab iframe content page and since it takes a few seconds to appears the iframe content of my site I'm wondering If I can place a loading gif inside the iframe to show first (maybe as a body background image) while its loading the rest of the content.

I see that the iframe ussually cames with all the images. So I'm wondering If there's any way to do this or the content of the iframe loads and is displayed all together.

I tried the image as body background and it didn't work. Both came together.

Comment: What does "Facebook tab iframe content page" mean?

Comment: In order for something like that to work you have to dynamically load your content through [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). [jQuery might simplify that a bit](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So basically you page would initially be the loading gif, while in the background you are fetching the content through the ajax call. When the content is ready replace the main container with the fetched content.

Comment: @TelmoMarques - If he's trying to show something in his own iframe before his content loads, he's kind of out of luck.  He can't even start to load his content with an ajax call until his scripts have loaded.  By then, he might as well just put up his progress message and let the regular page load happen.  So, I don't think loading by ajax really buys much.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the contents of an iframe that comes from a different domain.

But, you can use absolute positioning from your main window to put an image over the top of the embedded iframe which can probably accomplish what you want without a lot of complication or change of your main page design.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DajS4

---

If your code is in the iframe and you want something displayed before your page loads into the iframe and you don't control the parent, then there is nothing to do.  You can't do anything dynamically until your code is loaded and by then the page will already be starting to show.

All you can do is to make something on your page load very, very quickly (perhaps like a small image in the first tag of the page) that should be one of the first things to show and then when your page successfully finishes loading, you would hide that small image.  Other than making something show quickly, you can't do anything until you load so you can't show anything before you load.  It would have to be the parent window that created you that did something earlier.

Comment: I am not too sure if this would work with facebook. All he is allowed to do is give the url to his iframe. If i understand correct, what @Martin wants to do is to display a loader while his frame is being loaded... since he cant modify facebook's code, he'd have to use AJAX to achieve this

Comment: @RoopakV - I see what you're saying.  I think I first interpreted the question the other way around.  In either case, I've added the other case to my answer now too.

Answer (score 0):

Umm,

I understand what you are trying to achieve. but the only way i know to achieve this would be to use ajax to load all your content.

Set the ajax function to run on page load. And in the body of the page place one of those gif loaders..

hope u understand what im trying to say!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to load your page.

```
<div id="loading">loading..</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none"></div>

$(function() {
    $('#content').load('http://url', function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

note: the location of all your javascript should be at the bottom of the page to improve load speed.